# Comparing product topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{C}$ denote the set of complex numbers. Let $T$ be the smallest topology on $\mathbb{C}$ such that singletons are closed. Let $T_{1}$ denote the smallest topology on $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ such that all the polynomials in $\mathbb{C}$[x,y] are continuous. Is this topology same as the product topology $T\times T$ on $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$?
My guess is that it is not true, but I am unable to prove it rigorously. Thanks for any help.

Comment: A polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is a function $f:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. Is the topology on the co-domain is the usual topology on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Do you observe that the topology $T$ on $\mathbb{C}$ is finite complement topology?

Comment: Oh! I just realised that this question is from 2014, I don't know if the question poster is even aware of this question.